# Website pages crawled entirely, thereafter only a 50% of pages are

Tags: seo, googlebot, web-crawlers, crawl-rate, crawl-budget

Any technical or implementation tips on how to improve the crawling of site pages, when a given site used to have most pages crawled on its launch and thereafter only > 50% of them are. This assumes there is no apparent penalty in place or a large number of low quality links. I'm suspecting crawling budget interest from the bots is a factor. The client site does have low domain authority, because it's fairly new. Here are some assumptions or/and questions:

1. Domain authority being low, could mean the bots crawled the site, exploring most initially, but thereafter deemed that only a given % was/were worthy at this point of being crawled again to be published in the SERPs, due to low authority - possible solution: boosting the authority over 6-12 month with links should remedy the situation? (most obvious route so far).
2. Any technical tweaks meanwhile which may be used? to bypass the low authority issue (new site) to force or encourage the bot to once again crawl all pages, not just 50% and list them in the SERPs...could adding a sitemap directly onto the homepage, to encourage a quicker reconsideration be worth any effort?

Any other routes or options to consider? As the building of links takes time and resources, before Google even discovers them, let alone see them in GSC.

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate for our canonical resource on getting reliably crawled and indexed by search engines. You're right that crawl budget due to low authority is a big concern in that respect. (1) should help, but as far as (2) goes I don't believe there are any shortcuts, aside from the general strategies presented in the linked canonical question.

Comment: ok thanks, appreciated